# Relative path(in CSS file) in Laravel mix

Tags: css, laravel, webpack, laravel-mix

I have following file structure:

**File structure**

```
example/
├── public/
│   ├── css
│   │     └── home
│   │         ├── app.css
│   │         └── app.css.map
│   ├── images
│   │   ├── a.jpg
│   │   └── b.jpg
└── resources/
    ├── scss
    │   ├── app.scss
    │   └── ....
    └── images
        ├── a.jpg
        └── b.jpg
```

```scss
//App.scss

background-image: url(../images/a.jpg);
```

After bundle and create `app.css` I need to relative path but that is routed from the root `/`.

**Actual Result:**

```css
background-image: url(/images/a.jpg);
```

**Expected Result:**

```css
background-image: url(../../images/a.jpg);
```

**I tested `processCssUrls: false` options and I don't want to use it**